# A word for a person who is a member of the military, police force or firefighting force?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to know if there is a word for a person who is a member of *the military*, *the police force*, or *the firefighting force*.

Comment: *Non-civilian* and *serviceman* (or *servicewoman*) are possible, although usage may vary from country to country. In particular, fire-fighters may insist that they are civilians.

Comment: @Rathony Got it, sir!

Comment: @SovereignSun Well, that's you told. Personally, I'm never polite to anyone. ;-)

Comment: I don't think there is a recognized term in US English which encompasses all of these.  "Service member" is used for military, but would not commonly be considered to apply to police or fire-fighters.

Comment: Depending on the context (as always), *uniformed personnel* might  encompass all the above.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Is there a term in your mother tongue that you are attempting to translate? If not, why do you suppose such a word exists in English? The role of the military, of the police, and of the fire squad are all very distinct in Anglo-American societies, and it would be fairly unusual to group the military with either the police or the fire departments.

Answer (score 1):

In the United States we distinguish civilian from military so it's a little more difficult to include all. For civilian roles, you can use the term "public safety," (as in, my son has found a career in public safety as an EMT with the police force. He works at the fire station.) but that doesn't include military members. Likewise, "servicemen and women" doesn't include firefighters and police officers.